# how do get the values by AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

is there any way to get the radio button value by using ajax code.  already i have used jquery.i have a five radio buttons with five different values.. how do i make it by ajax. how to give the name in data url. button `NAME=code` .. need some example. `

```
..$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "include/make.php",  `
```

can any one tell me clearly

thanks
nancy

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but for instance if you're trying to trigger the ajax call when the button is clicked:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=xyz]").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/make.php",
        data: {name: this.value}
    });
});
```

...will call `make.php` with a `name` field set to the `value` property of the radio button that was clicked. Above I've used the name "xyz" for the radio buttons, but obviously switch that to be whatever their actual name is. You said you wanted to send the name of the radio button, but I've assumed you wanted its *value*, since of course the name wouldn't vary in the above (it would always be "xyz").

If you really want its *name*, I assume you'll be hooking the event on more radio buttons. This example hooks *all* radio buttons on the page, and sends their `name` and `value` to `make.php`:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/make.php",
        data: {name: this.name, value: this.value}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help (your question is not clear)

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "include/make.php", 
        data: "myval1=" + $("#myradiobtn1").val() + "&myval2=" +  $("#myradiobtn2").val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form you can use for example [jQuery's serializeobject plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-serializeobject-plugin) to mine out data from a form.

Answer (score -2):

```
    function getData(check_val)
{
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();    
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
//alert("hi");
    if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
    {
      XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", 'include/make.php');

      XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
        {
            //document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML="";
              XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
        }
      }

      XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1. The OP is using jQuery, so raw XHR stuff doesn't make much sense. 2. You've shown making an XHR request, but not how to connect it up to a radio button.

Comment: And yet, not helpful. First off, you're not showing the call, and -- again -- you're completely unnecessarily doing raw XHR stuff when the OP has specifically indicated she's using a library. Sorry, but -1.